# Prevent ZFS pool automount

Tags: grub2, manjaro, zfs, automounting

There's a Manjaro installation on ZFS that I'd like to `chroot` into from a rescue system on a USB stick. When booting the rescue system, the ZFS pools are automatically detected and mounted, if possible.

A problem arises when these mounts shadow existing folders, like `/tmp`, `/home` or `/root`. I cannot `chroot` into the system, because only some pools are mounted. `/` is not, for example. The solution to

1. export
2. import without mount
3. mount manually in the right order (first root, then everything else on top of it)

does not work, because the export fails: "busy". I can't unmount the folders that are in use.

I'd like to avoid to manually change the mountpoints of the pools to altroot `/mnt` and change back afterwards. Is there a solution to prevent the auto-mount during boot?

Using 20.2 Nibia.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `zfs set canmount=noauto <pool name>`, reboot and this should prevent the pools to mount automatically and shadow the previous mount data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try booting to a good, working ZFS system.  Import and mount your USB-stick rescue pool:

```
# zpool import -R /mnt rescue
```

This will mount the `rescue` pool under `/mnt`.

Erase `/etc/zfs/zpool.cache` from the `rescue` pool, and then export `rescue`:

```
# rm /mnt/etc/zfs/zpool.cache
# zpool export rescue
```

Then try rebooting to the USB stick.